# Spring Content Negotiation / OpenCSV: Getting a blank CSV

Tags: java, spring, csv

I'm using Spring's Content Negotiation and OpenCSV to output a CSV file to the client.

So I have this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
@esponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Model getCustomersView(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)
    throws InvalidBusinessContractDataException {
    Customer[] customers = customerService.findCustomers();
    return model.addAttribute("customers", customers);
}
```

And this Media Type Translator:

```
@Component("viewNameTranslator")
public final class MediaTypeRequestToViewTranslator implements
        RequestToViewNameTranslator {
    @Autowired
    private ContentNegotiationManager contentNegotiationManager;

    private DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator defaultTranslator = new DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator();

    // a list of media types to ignore - not output on the translated view
    private List<String> ignoredTypes = Arrays.asList("text/html");

    @Override
    public String getViewName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // first resolve the media type (see below)
        String mediaType = resolveMediaType(request);

        // delegate to the default translator to get the view name
        String viewName = defaultTranslator.getViewName(request);

        // concatenate the resolved media type to the default name and return it
        return viewName + mediaType;
    }

    private String resolveMediaType(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            // use the content negotiation manager to resolve the media type
            // from the request. The manager does it
            // according to its own search path and preferences - using the
            // suffix, using the Accept header and
            // preferring one of them. The result would always be a single type
            // or none at all, but it returns a list
            List<MediaType> types = contentNegotiationManager
                    .resolveMediaTypes(new ServletWebRequest(request));

            // resolve to a single type
            String type = types == null || types.size() == 0 ? "" : types
                    .get(0).toString();

            // if it's not in the ignored media types - prepend a semi-colon and
            // return it
            return ignoredTypes.contains(type) ? "" : ";" + type;
        } catch (HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And this view:

```
@Component("customers;text/csv")
public final class CustomerCsvView implements View {
    @Override
    public String getContentType() {
        return "text/csv";
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Map<String, ?> model, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        Customer[] customers = (Customer[]) model.get("customers");


        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response
                .getOutputStream()));

        writer.writeNext(new String[] {"id", "fName", "lName"});
        for (Customer c : customers) {
                    System.out.println("FOO");
            writer.writeNext(new String[] {
                    new Long(c.getCustomerId()).toString(), c.getFirstName(), c.getLastName() });
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit this controller with a browser, "FOO" appears in my console twice, a file save dialogue pops up with a test/csv file to download, and it is 0 bytes.

It's like changes to the response are not kept.

What's up?

Comment: are you using spring 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set content type and flush data before sending it, then close outputwriter

```
response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=utf-8")
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\yourData.csv\"");


OutputStream resOs= response.getOutputStream();  
OutputStream buffOs= new BufferedOutputStream(resOs);   
OutputStreamWriter outputwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(buffOs);  

CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(outputwriter);  

 // write data in csvwrite in loop
```

finally close flush and close it.

```
outputwriter.flush();   
outputwriter.close();
```

---

It will be better if you will use  [@ResponseBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) [HttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html) with spring 3.0

IN you controller you do like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFullData2.html", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "text/csv")
@ResponseBody // indicate to use a compatible HttpMessageConverter
public CsvResponse getFullData(HttpSession session) throws IOException {
      List<CompositeRequirement> allRecords = compReqServ.getFullDataSet((String) session.getAttribute("currentProject"));
      return new CsvResponse(allRecords, "yourData.csv");
}
```

Write HttpMessageConverter:

```
public class CsvMessageConverter extends AbstractHttpMessageConverter<CsvResponse> {
   public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = new MediaType("text", "csv", Charset.forName("utf-8"));
   public CsvMessageConverter() {
       super(MEDIA_TYPE);
   }

   protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
       return CsvResponse.class.equals(clazz);
   }

   protected void writeInternal(CsvResponse response, HttpOutputMessage output) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
       output.getHeaders().setContentType(MEDIA_TYPE);
       output.getHeaders().set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + response.getFilename() + "\"");
       OutputStream out = output.getBody();
       CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out), '\u0009');
       List<CompositeRequirement> allRecords = response.getRecords();
       for (int i = 1; i < allRecords.size(); i++) {
            CompositeRequirement aReq = allRecords.get(i);
            writer.write(aReq.toString());
       }
       writer.close();
   }
}
```

**A simple object to bind**

```
public class CsvResponse {    
   private final String filename;
   private final List<CompositeRequirement> records;

   public CsvResponse(List<CompositeRequirement> records, String filename) {
       this.records = records;
       this.filename = filename;
   }
   public String getFilename() {
       return filename;
   }
   public List<CompositeRequirement> getRecords() {
       return records;
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course, /facepalm.  So - how is HttpMessageConverter better and can you point me towards a tutorial?